# В IDEA пропала подсветка синтаксиса, кнопки run напротив кода и предложения по коду

Tags: intellij-idea

Пробовал переустановить idea  (удалить и скачать новый экзешник), но идея открывает старый проект как ни в чем не бывало (и тема и плагины как были установлены), при этом компиляция работает.
(До возникновения проблемы новые плагины не устанавливались и win 10  не обновлялась)

Подскажите как решить проблему, если кто встречался с такой или как полностью стереть идею с пк и скачать заново (заводские настройки)

idea версии 2022.2

Comment: Переустанови винду) А если серьёзно то нужно в программах и компонентах удалять программы, а  не ехе-шник. Ну или на крайняк можно самому файлы чистить. (Не забываем и про регистр)

Comment: Я удалял с помощью iobit uninstaller